# WebAPI and 401 vs 200

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am building a WebAPI as a learning project and attempting to use best practices. My first attempt is a authentication API, which takes an authentication object (JSON):

```
{
   username: myusername, 
   password: mypassword
}
```

it calls my API on /api/authenticate as a POST, passing the object.

In my .Net code, I do some checks, and if the username/password pass, I create a jwt token, and return it with roles. My API returns a 200 with the token in the body (response in Chrome developer tools shows "ey.....", which is my jwt).

If I get an invalid username/password, I return a 401.

I'm not sure this is right. Should I rather return a 200 - and some other payload in the body? (Not sure what), and then should my successful login return JSON, such as:

```
{
  success: true,
  error: null
  token: "ey.....",
}
```

A failed login return:

```
{
  success: false,
  error: null
  token: null,
}
```

and then an error:

```
{
  success: false,
  error: 500
  token: null,
}
```

And then client side code uses that to decide what to do? I'm trying to work on a best practice here to learn how to handle this in WebAPI.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here 1) What to return for errors, JSON or HTTP errors? 2) My code doesn't get the JSON object from my API. You shouldn't ask more than one question in your post. I've already answered the first question and some others may add more answers. I recommend removing the second question, copy it and create another question.

Comment: Use both - return 401 (don't return 200 as it indicates success), and also return json in body with detailed description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is really a "best practice" here. Some APIs return an error object like you did with JSON. That's completely fine. Other APIs return HTTP errors (401, 500, etc...). Other APIs return both. There are pros and cons to each method, so choose whatever you like or suits your needs best.

If you go with the first method, don't limit yourself to returning HTTP codes. Instead, return codes that give you and the consumers of your API more specific references to the errors. For example, code 401 doesn't tell me why the authentication failed. Probably that's fine for security, but I'm only using it here as an example, so instead you can return code 1001 for incorrect credentials, 1002 for an account that is locked, 1003 for an account that is pending approval, etc...

Pros of the first method: the API consumer can handle everything in the same code using a simple `if...else` or `switch` logic. It is also easier to test. The cons: you still need to use `try...catch`, because the request to the API may still fail, so the consumer code will have the above logic plus the `try...catch` logic.

Pros of the second method: it is more inline with the way we usually do things. Use `try...catch` to handle all errors, and the code inside will only be for the successful path. The cons: a little harder to test and you're stuck with the HTTP error codes.

The third method is a combination of the two. In some cases it is probably an overkill and adds some unnecessary complexity and repetition, but in other cases it can combine the benefits of the two worlds.

Answer (score 0):

> Here I give a different way of returning response message...
>   I hope, This will help you in returning the response message...

// For login success

> In the below code, it shows the success response...
>
> **return Content(HttpStatusCode.Ok, error);** This will helps to return the status code in the header of the **Postman Tool**.

```
if (result == null)
            {
                var error = new
                {
                    Success = "true",
                    Token = "your token"
                };
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.Ok, error);
            }
```

//for Unauthorized user login

> In the below code, it shows the Unsuccess login response...
>
> Here we can mention the error status to the user in response...
>   **return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorised, error);** This will helps to return the status code in the header of the **Postman Tool**.

```
if (result == some condition)
                 {
                     var error = new
                     {
                         Error = new
                         {
                             StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorised,
                             Message = "Invalid Credential...! ",
                             InternalMessage = "Some message"
                         }
                     };
                     return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorised, error);
                 }
```

// for error

> In the below code, it shows the Unsuccess login response...
>
> Here we can mention the error status to the user in response...
>   **return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);** This will helps to return the status code in the header of the **Postman Tool**.

```
if (result == somecondition)
             {
                 var error = new
                 {
                     Error = new
                     {
                         StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                         Message = "Error in functionality...!",
                         InternalMessage = "Some message"
                     }
                 };
                 return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
             }
```